# In Python, how can I make a function accept a sequence of variables embedded in a string?

Tags: python

In Python:

```
a = "l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]"
# l[0] etc. have their own value

my_function(a) #doesn't work


#but this does work
my_function(l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3])
```

Can the string a be 'transformed' so that the function sees the variables?
Thank you.

Later update: Thank you for answering my question.
I am including the bigger problem and why I had to resort to the eval function (not desired according to your answers).
The function:

```
class Line(object):
def __init__(self, pt1, pt2, *pt):
    pt1 = Point(pt1[0],pt1[1])
    pt2 = Point(pt2[0],pt2[1])
    self.vertices = [pt1, pt2]
    for i in pt:
        self.vertices.append(Point(i[0],i[1]))

def __getitem__(self, key):
    pt = self.vertices[key]
    p = Point(p[0],p[1])
    return p

#Here is the part with the issue:

def move(self, dx, dy):
    pts = len(self.vertices)
    l = self.vertices

    pt1 = Point(Point(l[0].x, l[0].y).move(dx, dy).x, Point(l[0].x, l[0].y).move(dx, dy).y)
    pt2 = Point(Point(l[1].x, l[1].y).move(dx, dy).x, Point(l[1].x, l[1].y).move(dx, dy).y)
    if pts == 2:
        mv = LineString(p1, p2)
    if pts > 2:
        bla = ''
        for i in [2,pts]:
            px = Point(l[i].x, l[i].y).move(dx, dy).x
            py = Point(l[i].x, l[i].y).move(dx, dy).y
            l[i] = Point(px,py)
            bla += 'l[' + str(i) + '], '
            arguments = bla[:-2]
            mv = LineString(pt1, pt2, *eval(arguments))
    return mv
```

According to your answers, there are better ways of solving this..

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the value of the string and how is your function defined?

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer - hoping I've understood you correctly.

Comment: Also, what you appear to be doing is looking like a terrible idea - what is the goal you're trying to achieve? And, even more importantly, who controls the content of the string?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this - there's got to be a bad design decision somewhere else if that's something you need to do.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, you've understood correctly, thank you

Comment: @user4815162342 ``[:-2]`` in the OP's code is intended to eliminate the trailing ``, ``. It must be absent in your improvement, otherwise it excludes the last two elements of your ``bla`` list

Comment: @eyquem Good point. Removing the comment, as your answer explains it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you can combine the `eval` function to evaluate the string with the `*` operator to apply `my_function` on the resulting tuple:

```
my_function(*eval(a))
```

However, doing this without a very good reason is almost always an indication of bad design. `eval` makes your code vulnerable to run-time errors and code injection attacks, and removes important performance optimizations. If you describe your actual requirements, it is likely that someone can propose a better solution.

Comment: You should alert @Tudor that "`eval()` is evil".

Comment: @user4815162342 I precise I'm not the downvoter. Your answer deserves to be accepted because you precisely answer to the concern of the OP and he is satisfied by the clear up. I've even just upvoted your answer, you will be able to verify this by the timestamps

Comment: @user4815162342 And now your rep has just passed 9000 :)

Comment: @eyquem Thanks for the clarification. I didn't consider you to be the downvoter, although the possibility had crossed my mind. I am honestly interested in the downvoter's reasoning, but hey - unexplained downvotes happen on SO. Other than that, I completely agree with your analysis. +1

Answer (score 3):

You had an [**XY** problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
Your real **X** problem was to pass an arbitrary number of objects to a function.
After having defined a string containing the identifiers of these objects, the **Y** solution to extract back the objects from this string became your graal.
But I'm pretty sure that the following snippet answers to your real **X** problem:

```
    if pts > 2:
        blal = []
        for i in [2,pts]:
            px = Point(l[i].x, l[i].y).move(dx, dy).x
            py = Point(l[i].x, l[i].y).move(dx, dy).y
            blal.append(Point(px,py))
        mv = LineString(pt1, pt2, *blal)
```

It's a facility offered by Python to pass arbitrary number of arguments to a function, not present in all programming languages. Would be a pity to complicate one's life , not using it.

I think that new members should be informed, or even prevented, not to upvote and accept answers too rapidly.

#### EDIT

I think that you can replace the code block in your question with this one:

```
from itertools import chain

class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, pt1, pt2, *pt):
        self.vertices = map(lambda x: Point(*x),
                            chain((pt1,pt2), pt))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Point(*self.vertices[key])

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        return LineString(*[ Point(Point(v.x, v.y).move(dx, dy).x,
                                   Point(v.x, v.y).move(dx, dy).y)
                             for v in self.vertices])
```

You could even define `Point()` in such a way that it would accept a couple (tuple, list... , I dont't know what your `pt`s are) instead of elements of `pt`
So, you could write `Point(x)` instead of `Point(*x)` and

```
self.vertices = map(Point, chain((pt1,pt2), pt))
```

instead of

```
self.vertices = map(lambda x: Point(*x),
                    chain((pt1,pt2), pt))
```

but would need to write `Point((v.x,v.y))` instead of  `Point(v.x,v.y)`

Comment: I did had a XY problem but I also wanted to find out the answer to my 'exact' question. mv in your answer is not correctly idented (- four spaces)

Comment: Godd point wanting to clear up all aspects. - I realize that a comment under your question gave the principle of my answer. However, I had thought about it before I've just seen this comment but I couldn't post the answer all yesterday.

Comment: Note that `map(lambda x: Point(*x), chain((pt1,pt2), pt))` is somewhat more idiomatically written as `[Point(*x) for x in chain((pt1, pt2), pt)]`.

Comment: user4815162342 Yes, and the list comp. is more readable, for me. But I think that the expression with a lambda function executes faster. It should be verified, though,

Answer (score 2):

Python methods take [arbitrary argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). What this means is that your function can take any number of arguments.

Here is an example:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   print args

foo('a','b','c','d')
```

Now, suppose you wanted to pass a list with values in it as arguments:

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
foo(mylist)
```

Now this will result in:

```
(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],)
```

A tuple with your list as the first argument. What we want is the same affect as `foo('a','b','c','d')`. To get that, we need to expand the list, like this:

```
foo(*mylist)
```

Now you'll get the same result:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

---

Taking this and applying it to your problem:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   print "Total arguments: {}".format(len(args))

v = "a, b, c"
>>> foo(v)
Total arguments: 1
>>> foo(*v.split(','))
Total arguments: 3
```

Comment: Nice little answer, but 1) it doesn't answer the question 2) A TUPLE HAS NO _"argument"_ BUT ELEMENTS 3) do we want **affect** or effect ?

Comment: The edit of your answer, with ``v = "a, b, c"`` puzzles me. It doesn't answer more to the question, which is in fact : how to extract several **objects** whose **identifiers** are present in a string. Doing ``foo("l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]")`` doesn't passes objects ``l[0]`` , ``l[1]`` , ``l[2]`` but doing ``foo(*"l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]".split(','))`` doesn't passes more these objects. 1] It still passes the individual identifiers extracted from the string, still not the objects 2] but it even doesn't extract them precisely, for example ``' l[1]'`` is extracted

Comment: @eyquem should we change the question to: "how to extract several objects whose identifiers are present in a string"?

Comment: By the way, reading the update of the question, it is clear that the OP hasn't a problem with the ability of the function to receive several arguments: the ``__init__`` function is defined as ``def __init__(self, pt1, pt2, *pt):``. This corroborates my feeling that you were off the question, and from the start since your answer began with _"Python methods take arbitrary argument lists."_

Comment: @Tudor You mean "the title" ?

Comment: @Tudor I don't know what should be the title. The fact is that you uses a words that is extremely confusing in Python : 'variable'. In Python we do not manipulate variables in the sense of "chunk of memory whose content can change", we have only access to identifiers and objects. Try to replace the word 'variable' in the title with something else and you'll begin to feel the problem.